# Peculiar problem with method naming in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have come across a peculiar issue in ASP.NET Core. I have a method which returns an entity after creation.

```cs
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetItemAsync(int id)
        {
            var entity = await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.FindByIdAsync(id);
            if (entity == null)
                return NotFound();
            return Ok(entity);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUser(UserNewDto userNewDto)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var entity = new User()
                {
                    UserName = userNewDto.UserName,
                    FirstName = userNewDto.FirstName,
                    LastName = userNewDto.LastName,
                    Email = userNewDto.Email,
                    PhoneMobile = userNewDto.PhoneMobile,
                    Password = userNewDto.Password,
                };

                await _unitOfWork.UserRepository.AddAsync(entity);
                await _unitOfWork.Complete();
                return CreatedAtAction("GetItemAsync", new { entity.Id }, entity);
            }

            return new JsonResult("Something went wrong") { StatusCode = 500 };
        }
```

The `CreateUser` method should redirect to `GetItemAsync` after creating the user. Instead, I get an error stating the following

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncCore(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Type objectType, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultAsync(IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResultFilterAsync[TFilter,TFilterAsync]()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

If I change the method name from `GetItemAsync` to `GetItem`, the redirection works as intended. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue in .net-core 3.0.  Please see [Async suffix removal from controller action names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#async-suffix-removal-from-controller-action-names):

> In ASP.NET Core 3.0, ASP.NET Core MVC removes the Async suffix from
> controller action names. Both routing and link generation are impacted
> by this new default.
>
> This change doesn't affect names specified using the `[ActionName]`
> attribute. The default behavior can be disabled with the following
> code in Startup.ConfigureServices:
>
> ```
> services.AddMvc(options =>
>     options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
> ```

So you could either:

1. Decorate your action with `[ActionName]`:

   ```
   [ActionName("GetItemAsync")]
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetItemAsync(int id)
   ```
2. Or setting `SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false` when configuring services:

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       services.AddControllers(options =>
           options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
   ```